# How to have a DataGridView inside a panel that has a header-row that scrolls with horizontal but not with vertical when the panel scrolls

Tags: c#, scroll, datagridview, panel, header-row

I have a DataGridView that uses a Panel for scroll to avoid the dreaded "Jump to beginning of list" DataGridView refresh issue.

What I'm looking for, is a header-row that stays visible during vertical scroll and moves along with horizontal scroll.

I tested this code in Visual Studio 2012, so it should run out of the box.

> Form1.designer.cs

```
namespace DataGridViewPanel
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // panel1
            // 
            this.panel1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.panel1.AutoScroll = true;
            this.panel1.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
            this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 73);
            this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
            this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(260, 177);
            this.panel1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // dataGridView1
            // 
            this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
            this.dataGridView1.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.None;
            this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(257, 174);
            this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 41);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.button1.Text = "Clear";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(197, 41);
            this.button2.Name = "button2";
            this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button2.TabIndex = 2;
            this.button2.Text = "Add Row";
            this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
            this.panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button2;
    }
}
```

> Form.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DataGridViewPanel
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fillDataGrid();
        }

        private void fillDataGrid()
        {
            dataBase Db = new dataBase();
            List<dataBase> DbList = new List<dataBase>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                DbList.Add(Db);
            }

            dataGridView1.DataSource = DbList;
            int width = 0;
            int height = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns) width += col.Width;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) height += row.Height;
            dataGridView1.Size = new Size(width, height);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataBase Db = new dataBase();
            List<dataBase> DbList = new List<dataBase>();

            DbList.Add(Db);


            dataGridView1.DataSource = DbList;
            int width = 0;
            int height = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns) width += col.Width;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) height += row.Height;
            dataGridView1.Size = new Size(width, height);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataBase Db = new dataBase();
            List<dataBase> DbList2 = new List<dataBase>();

            DbList2 = (List<dataBase>)dataGridView1.DataSource;

            dataGridView1.DataSource = null;

            DbList2.Add(Db);


            dataGridView1.DataSource = DbList2;
            int width = 0;
            int height = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns) width += col.Width;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) height += row.Height;
            dataGridView1.Size = new Size(width, height);
        }


    }

    public class dataBase : IEnumerable<string>
    {
        public string one { get; set; }
        public string two { get; set; }
        public string three { get; set; }
        public string four { get; set; }
        public string five { get; set; }
        public string six { get; set; }
        public string seven { get; set; }
        public string eight { get; set; }
        public string nine { get; set; }
        public string ten { get; set; }

        public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
        {
            yield return one;
            yield return two;
            yield return three;
            yield return four;
            yield return five;
            yield return six;
            yield return seven;
            yield return eight;
            yield return nine;
            yield return ten;
        }
        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We should probably focus on:  `"Jump to beginning of list" DataGridView refresh issue.`

Comment: Modify the datasource and there is no "dreaded jump to start" issue.  If you remove the datasource and provide a new one, you *are* starting over

Comment: My DataSource is a List<>
If I add a row to update the list no change happens to the DataGridVeiw1
@Plutonix

Comment: A BindingList<> would be the better choice than a List<>

Comment: BindingList is working well. I have included an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved a workable solution with an overlapping panel.
I created a second panel and DataGridView. I populate the second datagrid with the header.
The panel1.Scroll is handled on horizontal scroll to move the panel2 scroll.
Because panel1 overlaps the scrollbar of panel2, a final panel1.BringToFront() in the scroll handler makes sure panel1 hides panel2 scrollbars.

> Form1.Designer.cs

```
namespace DataGridViewPanel
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
        this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
        this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.panel2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
        this.dataGridView2 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
        this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
        this.panel2.SuspendLayout();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView2)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // panel1
        // 
        this.panel1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.panel1.AutoScroll = true;
        this.panel1.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
        this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 107);
        this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
        this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(260, 207);
        this.panel1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.panel1.Scroll += panel1_Scroll;
        // 
        // dataGridView1
        // 
        this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
        this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
        this.dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
        this.dataGridView1.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.None;
        this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(257, 204);
        this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 41);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.button1.Text = "Clear";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        // 
        // button2
        // 
        this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(197, 41);
        this.button2.Name = "button2";
        this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button2.TabIndex = 2;
        this.button2.Text = "Add Row";
        this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
        // 
        // panel2
        // 
        this.panel2.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.panel2.AutoScroll = true;
        this.panel2.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView2);
        this.panel2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 84);
        this.panel2.Name = "panel2";
        this.panel2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(260, 42);
        this.panel2.TabIndex = 1;
        // 
        // dataGridView2
        // 
        this.dataGridView2.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.dataGridView2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.dataGridView2.Name = "dataGridView2";
        this.dataGridView2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(257, 40);
        this.dataGridView2.TabIndex = 3;
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 326);
        this.Controls.Add(this.panel2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        this.panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
        this.panel2.ResumeLayout(false);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView2)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }



        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView2;
    }
}
```

> Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DataGridViewPanel
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private dataBase Db = new dataBase();
        private List<dataBase> DbList = new List<dataBase>();
        private List<dataBase> headList = new List<dataBase>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fillDataGrid();
        }

        private void fillDataGrid()
        {
            //add ten rows to the List
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                DbList.Add(Db);
            }

            //add one row to the List to populate headers
            headList.Add(Db);

            //populate datagrid by setting datasource
            dataGridView1.DataSource = DbList;
            dataGridView2.DataSource = headList;

            resizeDataGrids();

        }

        private void resizeDataGrids()
        {
            //resize the datagrids so the panels enable the scrollbars when required

            int width = 0;
            int height = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns) width += col.Width;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) height += row.Height;
            dataGridView1.Size = new Size(width, height);

            width = 0;
            height = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView2.Columns) width += col.Width;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows) height += row.Height;
            dataGridView2.Size = new Size(width, height);

            //bring panel1 to front
            panel1.BringToFront();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //populate datagridview1 with an empty List
            DbList = new List<dataBase>();
            DbList.Add(Db);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = DbList;
            resizeDataGrids();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //populate datagridview1 with List after adding a new row to the List
            DbList = (List<dataBase>)dataGridView1.DataSource;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
            DbList.Add(Db);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = DbList;
            resizeDataGrids();
        }

        void panel1_Scroll(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            //Handle horizontal scroll
            if (e.ScrollOrientation == System.Windows.Forms.ScrollOrientation.HorizontalScroll)
            {

                panel2.HorizontalScroll.Value = panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value;
                panel1.BringToFront();
            }
        }

    }

    public class dataBase : IEnumerable<string>
    {
        public string one { get; set; }
        public string two { get; set; }
        public string three { get; set; }
        public string four { get; set; }
        public string five { get; set; }
        public string six { get; set; }
        public string seven { get; set; }
        public string eight { get; set; }
        public string nine { get; set; }
        public string ten { get; set; }

        public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
        {
            yield return one;
            yield return two;
            yield return three;
            yield return four;
            yield return five;
            yield return six;
            yield return seven;
            yield return eight;
            yield return nine;
            yield return ten;
        }
        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Plutonix, I tried to only update the DataSource.

Using a couple for loops I populate a DataSet connected to the DataGridView1 DataSource. I like this because it eliminates the panel.

I was still able to use a List<>!

Thanks @Plutonix!

> Form1.designer.cs

```
namespace DataGridViewPanel
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 41);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.button1.Text = "Clear";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        // 
        // button2
        // 
        this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(197, 41);
        this.button2.Name = "button2";
        this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button2.TabIndex = 2;
        this.button2.Text = "Add Row";
        this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
        // 
        // dataGridView1
        // 
        this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 102);
        this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
        this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(259, 212);
        this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 3;
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 326);
        this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        }



        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;
    }
}
```

> Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DataGridViewPanel
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private dataBase Db = new dataBase();
        private List<dataBase> DbList = new List<dataBase>();
        private DataSet Ds = new DataSet();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //createColumns();
            createColumns();

            fillDataGrid();

            //populate datagrid by setting datasource
            dataGridView1.DataSource = Ds.Tables[0];
        }

        private void AddRow()
        {
            dataBase db = new dataBase();
            db.one = DateTime.Now.Day.ToString();
            db.two = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();
            db.three = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
            db.four = DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString();
            db.five = DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString();
            db.six = DateTime.Now.Second.ToString();
            db.seven = DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString();

            DbList.Add(db);

            fillDataGrid();
        }

        private void fillDataGrid()
        {

            for (int i = DbList.Count - 1; i > Ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i--)
            {
                Ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add();
                int loop = 0;
                foreach (string valueStr in DbList[i])
                {
                    int end = Ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1;
                    Ds.Tables[0].Rows[end][loop] = valueStr;
                    loop++;
                }

            }


        }

        private void createColumns()
        {
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                {
                    Ds.Tables.Add(new DataTable());
                    Ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("one");
                    Ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("two");
                    Ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("three");
                    Ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("four");
                    Ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("five");
                    Ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("six");
                    Ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("seven");
                    Ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("eight");
                    Ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("nine");
                    Ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("ten");
                }));

        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //populate datagridview1 with an empty List
            DbList = new List<dataBase>();
            Ds.Clear();

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //populate datagridview1 with List after adding a new row to the List
            //Ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(Db);
            AddRow();
        }


    }

    public class dataBase : IEnumerable<string>
    {
        public string one { get; set; }
        public string two { get; set; }
        public string three { get; set; }
        public string four { get; set; }
        public string five { get; set; }
        public string six { get; set; }
        public string seven { get; set; }
        public string eight { get; set; }
        public string nine { get; set; }
        public string ten { get; set; }

        public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
        {
            yield return one;
            yield return two;
            yield return three;
            yield return four;
            yield return five;
            yield return six;
            yield return seven;
            yield return eight;
            yield return nine;
            yield return ten;
        }
        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with a BindingList as suggested by @LarsTech. This is very simple compared to a List<>/DataSet/DataGridView.

> Form1.Designer.cs

```
namespace DataGridViewPanel
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
        this.button3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 41);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.button1.Text = "Clear";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        // 
        // button2
        // 
        this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(197, 41);
        this.button2.Name = "button2";
        this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button2.TabIndex = 2;
        this.button2.Text = "Add";
        this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
        // 
        // dataGridView1
        // 
        this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 102);
        this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
        this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(259, 212);
        this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 3;
        // 
        // button3
        // 
        this.button3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(104, 41);
        this.button3.Name = "button3";
        this.button3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button3.TabIndex = 4;
        this.button3.Text = "Remove";
        this.button3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button3.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button3_Click);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 326);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button3);
        this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }



        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button3;
    }
}
```

> Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DataGridViewPanel
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private dataBase Db = new dataBase();
        private BindingList<dataBase> DbList = new BindingList<dataBase>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //populate datagrid by setting datasource
            dataGridView1.DataSource = DbList;
        }

        private void AddRow()
        {
            //create a new set of data
            dataBase db = new dataBase();
            db.one = DateTime.Now.Day.ToString();
            db.two = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();
            db.three = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
            db.four = DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString();
            db.five = DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString();
            db.six = DateTime.Now.Second.ToString();
            db.seven = DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString();

            //add data to the list
            DbList.Add(db);

        }

        private void removeRow()
        {
            //check if cells are selected
            if (dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
            {
                //loop while rows are selected
                while (dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
                {
                    //remove selecteed cell 0
                    DbList.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex);
                }
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //populate datagridview1 with an empty List
            DbList.Clear();

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //add a new row to the List
            AddRow();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //remove a row from the list
            removeRow();
        }

    }

    //custom class with string enumeration
    public class dataBase : IEnumerable<string>
    {
        public string one { get; set; }
        public string two { get; set; }
        public string three { get; set; }
        public string four { get; set; }
        public string five { get; set; }
        public string six { get; set; }
        public string seven { get; set; }
        public string eight { get; set; }
        public string nine { get; set; }
        public string ten { get; set; }

        public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
        {
            yield return one;
            yield return two;
            yield return three;
            yield return four;
            yield return five;
            yield return six;
            yield return seven;
            yield return eight;
            yield return nine;
            yield return ten;
        }
        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```